# CakePHP 3: How to include simple page .ctp in default.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Is it possible? if yes, then how to create a simple page that uses the `default.ctp` page.

So I want something like the "include" features because my single pages have the same header and footer as my `default.ctp` and I don't want to write the import scripts (css, js) twice because the paths are differents from `src/Template/Layout/default.ctp` and `src/Template/Pages/*.ctp`

Thank you. I'm a newbie on CakePHP and I started with version 3.

Comment: Here do you want to use the default.ctp layout ,in your page? If yes,then you can call the layout by calling  $this->layout="default"; I have used this functionality in cake php version 2.9,hope it will work for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your **Controller's View Function**:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('custom');
```

This will use src/Templates/Layout/custom.ctp file instead of default.ctp

You can (but you shouldnt), only add few html tags on this file and populate everything else in your src/Templates/Pages/*.ctp files

Comment: Don't really un derstand your solution. Where should I put `$this->viewBuilder()->layout('custom');` Could you explain more please.

Comment: @levolutionniste in your PagesController, function beforeFilter(){ $this->viewBuilder()->layout('custom'); }